# Does explicitly specifying non-ambigous types of relations and nodes improve a cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose nodes of type `A` have only one kind of outgoing relations (for example `[:relType]`) and only to other nodes of type `(:A)`.

Does specifying explicitly the types of nodes and relations improve the query and its response time?

i.e.:

is a query such as

```
MATCH p=(:A)-[]->() RETURN p;
```

less efficient than:

```
MATCH p=(:A)-[:relType]->(:A) RETURN p;
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated]

In general, if you know that there is only one possible relationship type (or node label), then not specifying it in a Cypher pattern would be faster. That is because the Cypher planner would then not generate an operation to verify the type (or label).

However, as @InverseFalcon's comment indicates, sometimes the Cypher planner may be able to use the type or label as a hint to enable it to speed up the overall query, despite the overhead of verifying the type (or label).

[Profiling](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) both versions of your query may be helpful in deciding which one to use.

Comment: That said, Neo4j does collect statistics, such as the count of relationships of types from certain node labels, and to certain node labels. If there are many outgoing :relType relations from :A nodes, but very few incoming :relType relations to :A nodes, then having the label would let the planner choose the more selective starting point and expansion.